# p2p_find is giving OK but not working correctly

Tags: p2p, wpa-supplicant

p2p_find
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED

-That's it, its not scanning recursively

wpa_supplicant v2.7 
***.conf(etc/wpa_supplicant/***.conf)file contains the following...

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

config_methods=pbc

update_config=1

ap_scan=1

device_name=MY_p2p

device_type=1-0050F204-1

p2p_listen_reg_class=81

p2p_listen_channel=1

Just want that to scan recursively and work normally as it does.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*i know it is a bad practice to answer you own post:/*

the issue was with the driver which was installed on the PC, it was not the correct driver for the PC. So i just installed the correct driver in my case and now the p2p_find and all commands in wpa is working fine..